# Empty log files daily using cron task

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cron

I want to empty (not delete) log files daily at a particular time. something like

```
echo "" > /home/user/dir/log/*.log
```

but it returns

```
-bash: /home/user/dir/log/*.log: ambiguous redirect
```

is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't redirect to more than one file, but you can `tee` to multiple files.

```
tee /home/user/dir/log/*.log </dev/null
```

The redirect from `/dev/null` also avoids writing an empty line to the beginning of each file, which was another bug in your attempt. (Perhaps specify `nullglob` to avoid creating a file with the name `*.log` if the wildcard doesn't match any existing files, though.)

However, a much better solution is probably to use the utility `logrotate` which is installed out of the box on every Debian (and thus also Ubuntu, Mint, etc) installation. It runs nightly by default, and can be configured by dropping a file in its configuration directory. It lets you compress the previous version of a log file instead of just overwrite, and takes care to preserve ownership and permissions etc.

Comment: Both methods works as expected. Thanks for introducing me logrotate tool